# Sending Information to a PHP Script using Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

I would like to send an ajax command to a php script each time when a button is clicked. The divs are called r, l, t, b for the different directions. So far I have tried using the code below. But somehow it doesn't work. I have not a lot of experience in jquery and that's why I am asking here for a simple solution. I could write 4 times the same function but this is certainly not what I am looking for.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

function control(id){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "control.php",
        data: {id: "1"},
        success:  function(data){
            alert(data);
        }
    });
}

$('#r').mousedown(function(){
    control($(this).attr('id'));
});

});
```

Comment: Describe "it doesn't work"

Comment: Does your php not catch it?  Does the AJAX call fire?   Have you put an `{error:function(){}}` into the ajax call to see if it actually was being fired?

Comment: What are you sending back from control.php.  Json? Html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to know exactly what you are asking, but basically you want a multipurpose click event for multiple divs.

in jQuery, you can add multiple selectors by separating the selectors  with commas
like so:

```
$('#id, .class, element')
```

Here is an example that uses less code to provide the same functionality, if I understood your question correctly.

```
$(function(){
    $('#r,#l,#t,#b').mousedown(function(){
        $.post('control.php',{id: $(this).attr('id')},function(data){
            //handle data callback
            alert(data);
        });
    });
});
```

I used `$.post` instead of `$.ajax` , but bear in mind if you use the simpler methods like post, get, or getJSON, you will not be able to assign an error callback as far as I'm aware. Hopefully this changes in future releases of jQuery.

Answer (score 3):

Well first...

Just give all your divs a class

```
 <div id="r" class="direction"></div>
  <div id="l" class="direction"></div>
    <div id="t" class="direction"></div>
      <div id="b" class="direction"></div>
```

Then rewrite your jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('.direction').mousedown(function(){
          $.post("control.php",{id: $(this).attr('id')},function(msg){
               alert(msg);
          });
      });
  });
```

If you happen to be receiving JSON from the servers....
You must specify the dataType as 'json' or 'jsonp' for cross domain json and use $.ajax

```
function control(theid){
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "control.php",
    data: {id: theid},
    dataType: 'json',
    success:  function(msg){
        alert(msg);
    }
});
```

}

Or if you wanna keep it simple like the above $.post example.....use getJSON

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.direction').mousedown(function(){
          $.getJSON("control.php",{id: $(this).attr('id')},function(msg){
               alert(msg);
          });
      });
  });
```

Comment: This was a very good answer as well, and its even better because you bind the event to a class instead of multiple id's. my answer works, but in my opinion this was the proper answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
function control(my_id){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "control.php",
        data: {id: my_id},
        success:  function(data){
            alert(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Using `$_POST['id'];` you should get the information you are looking for.